# Where to get Visual Studio LightSwitch 2012 Server Runtime from in Web Platform Installer?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have upgraded my 2011 Lightswitch app to 2012 RTM and it works fine locally. However, when I try to Publish it to my web server it fails (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/03/23/deployment-guide-how-to-configure-a-web-server-to-host-lightswitch-applications.aspx).

I checked the Web Platform Installer on the live server and it does NOT have "**Visual Studio LightSwitch 2012 Server Runtime without Local SQL**" ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg481779(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg481779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) - it only has the 2011 version.

Where do I get the **2012** version from? There is very little info about it on the web.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2012/03/29/lightswitch-iis-deployment-enhancements-in-visual-studio-11.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2012/06/27/10145037.aspx?PageIndex=4

Comment: This still talks about 2011, not 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I am going to summarise my experience here as it might help others who are upgrading. My app uses the Telerik RadgridView control and Forms authentication. It runs OOB:

1) Firstly, I upgraded to the RTM LS2012 version and rebuild my app - all works fine on Dev.

2) I then tried to deploy to my Win2008 Server with no changes (note: it was running the LS2011 version with no problems). This failed with an "Unknown" message during the publish process. To get around this I unchecked the flag on the Publish wizard "IIS Server has the Lightswitch Deployment Prerequisites".

3) Next problem: The Silverlight App would show "loading" and then show a blank screen. At one point I received a message saying "**Debugging resource strings are unavailable**". The problem here was that the IIS site that the publishing wizard created had Windows and Forms Authentication (under the IIS Authentication icon). Disabling Windows Auth solved this problem. I was finally able to log on to my app.

4) Hardest problem: The app would log in and work fine for about 20 seconds. Then it would throw a Silverlight unhandled exception: "**Unhandled exception at 0x5ceed700 in sllauncher.exe: 0xC0000 094: Integer division by zero**". After a lot of Googling someone asked if I was using a VM - the server IS a VM and they suggested I run as a single processor (ie. it was a threading error). I did not try this, instead I tried running from a different PC as a client OOB (I was testing on the server). This then worked.

After all this my app is now up and running as Lightswitch 2012.... hope this helps someone!

**Notes**: I did NOT install .NET 4.5 (my projects target .NET 4) OR the Lightswitch 2012 requisites on the server. It works with the Silverlight 4 Telerik dlls.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is change of .NET framework from 4.0 to 4.5 in your application directory.

Comment: Do you mean on the IIS App Pool?

Answer (score 0):

It is called "LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012 - Server Configuration with(out) local SQL Express" and available at the Web Platform Installer.